How do I download bowtie2 onto my macbook?
I was told I need to first make a virtual environment that runs on Python 3.5. I tried to use the command:
conda create -n p35env python=3.5

But I keep getting the message:
(base) Drews-MacBook-Pro:~ drewramos$ conda create -n p35env python=3.5
Channels:
 - bioconda
 - conda-forge
 - defaults
Platform: osx-arm64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - python=3.5*

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge
  - defaults

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.

Do I need to add specific channels?
If someone can give me a detailed description of how to download bowtie 2, I would be extremely grateful. (I am not very tech savy)
My attempted code:
conda create -n p35env python=3.5
conda activate p35env
conda install bioconda::bowtie2


Any reason why you need specifically python version 3.5, as opposed to letting conda install the current default python version?

Generally, my recommendation is to always read and apply the manual first without modifications.
In this case, visit https://anaconda.org/bioconda/bowtie2 which instructs to use the command conda install bioconda::bowtie2. This will take care of all dependencies including the python version. Python 3.5 is very old, it is not surprising this chokes up here.
Indeed creating a separate environment (via conda) makes a lot of sense, since it keeps things tidy and clean. Individual tools might have conflicting dependencies so a fresh environment is almost always helpful.
Here, just use conda create --name bowtie2_env, something like that.
Note that using mamba over conda these days is imo recommended as it speeds up things a lot and sometimes solves conflicts better.
